# Delete a record from console -- Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to delete a record from the console.

I logged through script/console and

```
User.find(1).delete
$<User id: 1, ..............>
User.find(1)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with ID=1
........
........
........
```

Everything looks fine till here.

But when I exit the console and return back to console by script/console command, I am able again to see the record with id = 1.

The database is not local and I'm connecting through database.yml by giving an ip.

when I try to do the same on the development local database, everything is fine.

Can someone please explain whats happening and where am I missing!

Thanks

Comment: do you have permission to write to remote DB with your login/pass?

Comment: I don't understand which login/pass, I can't ssh to the remote DB. I am completely kind of new to this kind of stuff. I am able to do everything and I think my username has every permissions like write, read, create. But I am not sure!

Comment: Can you paste the actual console session? Also, are you sure you are connecting to the production database?

Comment: Devin, I am connecting to the production database. I am sure I want to delete the records in the table. I will try to post the session

Comment: You may not have rights to delete.

Comment: James, Thank you! So if I have the permissions, I should be able to do it rite?

Comment: Did you override the delete method?

Comment: Lichtamberg, Nope I didn't override the delete method. I guess I am in linux sandbox mode.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try

```rb
User.find(1).destroy
```

This should work in the console and otherwise.

Comment: User model got some call_backs and I don't want to touch them. That is the reason y I went with delete.

Comment: when I invoke console, I am invoking in sandbox mode. (script/console -s development) which I shouldn't do. Thank you for your help guys.

Comment: Its my bad...I am invoking the console in Sandbox mode and now I disabled it and its working fine...ofcourse sorry for the late solution....

Answer (score 3):

On a similar note you can remove all the tuples for a given Object from the rails console as follows:

```rb
@object = Object.all

@object.each do |o|
  o.delete
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy way to remove Models data from console

```
rails console
```

Store user model to an instance variable

```
user = User.find(1)
```

delete or destroy the relations by following commands

```
user.delete
```

or

```
user.destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

Try User.count or y User.count

User.first where first is the number you want to delete

User.first.destroy

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't invoking console in sandbox mode, which will prevent the delete operation.