# Attempting to destroy a record in my database using the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console, pry

So I was working on something and wound up having to dump multiple test dummy records in my database. Unfortunately i've been having a very difficult time figuring out how to get those deleted.

I then opened up my rails console ran

```
Players.count
```

..which gave me 93 players. I only have 73 'real' players. I also noticed that the players names i had given them were test!!!

And so I ran this command here

```
player = Players.where(name: "test!!!")
```

and received a list of the 20 players named 'test!!!'

I then went and ran this command

```
player.each(&:destroy)
```

at first the output looked really nice and it looked like everything had been taken care of. However, after scrolling down further to the very end to my utter dismay i ran into these outputs

```
 (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed: ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed
```

....and after looking at that, I re-ran

```
Players.count
```

and became disappointed to see that the same 93 players were still there. :(

I will admit that I am very much a junior when it comes to ruby on rails and such. So I will admit there is likely something that I am quite possibly missing with this one, but would anybody be able to take a look at it?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069221/delete-a-record-from-console-ruby-on-rails - just find by name instead of id

Comment: Are you committed to using the Rails console for this task?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to delete players with the name `test!!!`. You'll need to run `destroy_all` on player, given that its a collection.

```
player = Players.where(name: "test!!!")
player.destroy_all
```

To delete one by one, it would be something like `player.first.destroy` or `player.last.destroy`

or find by its `id` and delete it, `Players.find(1).destroy`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I just tried that, but I did not get anywhere with it. I essentially got the same rollback error as before.

Comment: can you share the player class? and model names should be singular, so instead of being Players, it should be Player, and file name should be player.rb

Comment: `destroy_all` can take a parameter for the search condition. So you can combine the two lines into one, as a shorter alternative: `Player.destroy_all(name: "test!!!")`. (and yes, model class names are singular by convention)